# Instanciate a component twice, each time with different sub-component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a `my-gallery` component containing `my-image` as sub-components, that represent images.

Basically, I have something like :

`my-app.component.htm`:

```
<gallery [imageList]="myImages"></gallery>
```

`my-gallery.component.htm`:

```
<my-image *ngFor="let image of imageList" [image]="image">
</my-image>
```

So far so good. Now I'd like to instantiate the `my-gallery` component twice, each time using a different sub-component (to get different image representations). But `my-image` is hard-coded in `my-gallery.component.htm`.

Let's say I'd like to sometimes use `my-image1`, and other times `my-image2`. I would expect to be able to write something like :

```
<gallery [imageList]="myImages1" subComponent="my-image1"></gallery>
<gallery [imageList]="myImages2" subComponent="my-image2"></gallery>
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

I'm not sure I can use [content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection) because I'm using 'ngFor' for each image...

Maybe I could pass a component name as an input of my-gallery, to instantiate my-image1 or my-image2 manually? But then my-images would need to be databound programmatically (if possible), I'm not sure it's the best way...

For sure, I'll create a base class for `my-image1` and `my-image2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well actually, content projection is the answer !

[Example demo for your use case](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxssy2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

[Documentation about complex content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional-content-projection)

The secret is to use `ng-template` and provide a context to the element. This way, you can make custom logic inside the base component to display it multiple times, and use the context to display the correct values !

Comment: Thank you, the demo is very helpful and a good place to dive into some Angular concepts (sometimes not really well documented).